# Добавление данных в таблицу БД через EF в MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Доброго времени суток. Возможно вопрос покажется тривиальным, но все же ответа в гугле я найти не смог.

**Исходные данные:** Есть проект на ASP.NET MVC, где с помощь Entity Framework создается таблица с вводимыми из обычной вьюшки данные пользователем.

**Проблема:** Следуйщий запуск приложение замещает данные, введенные ранее. Цель - добавлять к данным с предыдущего запуска приложения. Метод SaveChanges() с msdm:

> Сохраняет все обновления в источнике данных и сбрасывает отслеживание изменений в контексте объекта.

К сожалению не смог найти метода, который добавляет, без сброса. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

**Реализация в коде:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller // Класс Контроллера
{
    VoteContext VC = new VoteContext();

 public string Vote(Voter voter) 
 {
    voter.Date = DateTime.Now;
    VC.Voter.Add(voter);
    VC.SaveChanges();
 }
```

P.S. View часть не участвует в этом процессе, поэтому вставлять ее я не стал.

Comment: так вам надо при запуске приложения проверять, если ваши иданные уже были добавлены в БД, то показывать их, или показывать что вы показываете по умолчанию

Comment: @tym32167 пользователь не должен видеть данных, а каждый раз делать загрузку из дб, думаю не целесообразно и ресурсоемко

Comment: Если вы не хотите данные грузить из бд, зачем вам бд? Или я не понял вашего вопроса

Comment: @tym32167 Данные должны сохранятся, вывод их происходит в другом месте через контроллер, не через View. Вопрос в том, как организовать процесс работы с БД, не для замещения данных, а для добавления после каждого перезапуска (не имею опыта работы с БД)

Comment: Попробуйте переформулровать вопрос, или покажите табличку в БД как у вас и как вам надо, а то я не могу никак понять вашу проблему.

Comment: @tym32167 После первого запуска приложения было введенно 10 полей, который сохранились в БД. После второго запуска приложения введено 5 полей, но перед их заполнением отчистились 10 с первого запуска. Моя проблема - в замещении. В итоге должно было получится 15, по факту - 5 после последнего запуска. Если бы метод SaveChanges имел аналог функции push и продвигал бы массив полученных полей, не было бы проблемы ):

Comment: Запускаете в дебагере? Или так на продакшене? Не в папке ли с программой лежит ваша бд?

Comment: @tym32167 Запускаю с дебагера - приложение тестовое, БД в папке.

Comment: И эта БД у вас ещё и в проекте поди, с опцией "Copy Always" лежит, так?

Comment: Сдается мне, каждый раз, когда вы запускаете приложение через студию, студия очищает вашу папку bin\debug, удаляя при этом БД, что там лежит, и копирует туда БД из проекта, которая пустая

Comment: Запустите ваш исполняемый файл из папки bin\debug напрямую и проверье, пропадают ли данные

Comment: @tym32167 Блин, вот и решение :) Сделайте копи-паст в ответ, поставлю лайк. Не знал о таких подводных камнях VS :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что когда добавляете файл БД в проект и ставите ему опцию `Copy Always`, то при каждом запуске приложения в выходной папке этот файл базы данных перезаписывается, отменяя этим все изменения, сделанные при предыдущем запуске.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: Раз помогло, отметье пжста ответ как правильный.