# C# EF6 что делаю не так?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Пытаюсь освоить EF6. Создал базу по схеме Model First. Ну и на данный момент реализую логику "если в базе не найдено ни одного пользователя тогда создаем дефалтного"
Вот реализация:

```
private void LoadUsers()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var CurentContext = new MedDBModelContainer())
            {
                var users = CurentContext.UsersSet.ToList();
                if (!users.Any())
                {
                    var default_user = GetAdmin(CurentContext);
                    CurentContext.UsersSet.Add(default_user);
                    CurentContext.Entry(default_user).State = EntityState.Added;
                    CurentContext.SaveChanges();
                    ExLog.Info("В настройках пользователей программы не обнаружено ни одного пользователя. Создан пользователь по умолчанию `Администратор`");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExLog.Error(ex.Message, ex);
            MessageBox.Show(
                "Возникла ошибка при получении списка пользователей. Обратитесь к вашему системному администратору.", "Опс, ошибка!");
        }
    }

    private Users GetAdmin(MedDBModelContainer CurentContext)
    {
        return new Users()
        {
            Dismissed = false,
            Firstname = "Администратор",
            Lastname = "Администратор",
            Middlename = "Администратор",
            Phone = "+71231231212",
            Roles = GetRole("Администратор", CurentContext)
        };
    }

    private Roles GetRole(string rolename, MedDBModelContainer CurentContext)
    {
        try
        {
            var Roles = CurentContext.RolesSet;
            if (Roles.Any())
            {
                return (CurentContext.RolesSet.Single(x => x.RoleName.Equals(rolename)));
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(
                    "Необходимо произвести настройку ролей. Обратитесь к вашему системному администратору.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExLog.Error(ex.Message, ex);
            MessageBox.Show("Ошибка получения ролей.", "Опс, ошибка!");
        }
        return new Roles();
    }
```

После выполнения по дебагу роль из базы получаю но пользователь не создается в базе. Почему?(

Comment: Попробуйте убрать строчку CurentContext.Entry(default_user).State = EntityState.Added;

Comment: Пробовал. Я ее собственно и добавил после того как без нее не сработало

Comment: https://github.com/ilchenkoevgeny/MedERP

Comment: у вас это что? консольное приложение? Сервис? Как вы БД добавили? Поди просто как файл в проект? Как вы проверяете, что юзера нет? Через перезапуск приложения? Покажите вашу строку сеодинения

Comment: Дайте угадаю, вы поди добавили БД как файл в проект, а строка соединения подключается по относительному пути. То есть у вас есть БД1 в проекте, и есть БД2 где вы добавляете юзера, она в папке bin/debug, и вы при запуске вашй программы через студию каждый раз затираете БД2 файлом из проекта БД1.

Comment: вот это ([1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/864664/179763), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1132387/179763), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/861713/179763), [4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/750262/179763)) выглядит как ваш случай?

Comment: Я вижу, что у вас походу настольное приложение. Открываете папку bin/debug, ищете там exe файлик, запускаете его, после в той же папке ищитие копию своей БД и смотрите что в ней. Если вы запускаете свое приложение через VisualStudio, то ваша БД папке будет перезаписана файлом БД из проекта, ге никаких изменений не происходило.

Answer (score 1):

```
var Roles = CurentContext.RolesSet;
```

Строчка выше - это запрос, который еще не выполнен.
Исправьте на:

```
var Roles = CurentContext.RolesSet.ToList();
```

Строчку ниже необходимо удалить. EF умный и сам определится с состоянием сущности.

```
 CurentContext.Entry(default_user).State = EntityState.Added;
```

Comment: Хочется надеяться но пока я ничего не могу записать в базу(

Comment: Удалил старую базу и старую модель. Все пересоздал заново. эффект тот же самый.

Comment: Еще смущает при генерации базы по модели получаю ошибку:
Сообщение 911, уровень 16, состояние 1, строка 12
Database 'MedDB' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
База добавлена в сам проект. Подключение к ней проходит. И сущности создаются в базе но ошибку пишет все равно.

Comment: Я соединялся с ms sql. В MS sql напишите CREATE DATABASE MedDB. Далее соединяетесь с вашей базой через Visual Studio и накатываете таблицы(или в ms выполняете MedDBModel.edmx.sql). После соединения с базой и внесения исправлений, которые описаны выше, все заработает. У меня заработало)

Comment: Ага, я по моему понял где косяк. Вы сделали базу в инстансе локального скл.
И тогда EF отрабатывает. У меня было иначе - база была добавлена через дерево объекта в сам проект. Поэтому EF глючит. Причем ее получается указать в строке подключения но работа с ней корректно не проходит.

Comment: Если такой косяк возникает. То пользуйтесь подходом CodeFirst. Создали базу, вручную импортировали туда данные из старой и работаете. Но я таких глюков с EF на практике не встречал и скорее всего у вас что-то неправильно.